# Should you use try/catch/finally blocks often

Tags: objective-c, ios

As a developer with java background I am used to often catching exceptions to prevent them from crashing my app. This includes all kinds of delegate methods. Just an extra safety measure for unexpected situations.

My question is whether such approach is sensible in objective c and does it introduce some sort of performance problems? I other words would my app suffer in any way if I use try/catch blocks more often?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't suffer that much, but you have to remember something. Unlike in other languages where you might have `ConnectionRefusedException` or `FileNonexistantException`, in objective-c, exceptions are programmer errors 90% of the time. So by the time your app enters production, it shouldn't have any exceptions anyway. Rather than, for example, catching out of bounds exceptions, just look at array length before trying. You can make a top level try-catch though just in case that gives the error and exits more gracefully than a crash.

Comment: Yes sure. Knowing that some exception is thrown sometimes and doing nothing about it is not ok. My intention is just to prevent my app from crashing in case something really unexpected happens.

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka: Then make one big try/catch around the entire app. The point is, for most normal operation errors, there are not exceptions, but rather NSError objects.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don’t want exceptions to occur while your program is running. So it’s considered better programming practice to test for errors before they occur rather than to catch them after they occur.

It’s also better to test for an error in a method and return some value as an error indicator than to throw an exception.Throwing exceptions use a lot of system resources, and, as such,

***Apple generally recommends against using their unnecessary use (e.g., you don’t want to throw an exception simply because you can’t open a file).***

Comment: You said *.Throwing exceptions use a lot of system resources, and, as such*. Could you please explain what exactly happens under the hood, when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Well the best practice is that you use try and catch only when you are loading data, modules, files and things that might not work due to user environment settings or user submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is *an exception*, and should not be happening that often : )), so it won't affect performance at all.

Usually protocols contain delegate methods for both normal behaviour and error [e.g. `didLoadResponse: theResponse`, `didFailWithError: theError`], so all situations will be covered.

I would reserve exception to situations like errors in writing to disk, or remote servers being down - actually situations that would break the application.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a performance problem.If an exception is thrown, that's fine while you debug the program.But while the application is run by there you may not want that this happens.
My suggestion is to use exceptions only for debug, then you disable them for the release and you use more suitable apporaches like NSError.
Let's suppose that the user types a URL and this URL is invalid.You have to load a web page.During the debug you may just throw an exception, but when you have the release you could just ignore the wrong URL, and don't display the page, or run a NSAlertPanel to display the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use tty/catch for exceptions only, not as a replacement for if/then.Overhead is very expensive.

Comment: Yea I see that now. Whoops. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please shed some light on what contributes to this "overhead"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing on an iPad.  It appears that a @try/@catch block introduces very little performance penalty unless an exception is actually thrown.  But if an exception is thrown, the penalty is substantial.  You don't say what environment you are using.  So your milage may vary.